# R subtract means within one variable/column based on another variable/column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` containing reaction time values, where I would like to subtract the mean reaction time based on the two values in `Congruency` column `"congruent" and "incongruent"`. 
However i further would like to do this substraction based on other the levels of other variables, specifically several variables at a time.

MWE:

```
   df <- data.frame(rt = c(764.2, 629.7, 629.7, 412.1, 538.1, 606.2, 348.7, 532.5, 436.7,490.2),
                          Congruency = c("incongruent", "congruent","congruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "incongruent", "congruent","congruent", "incongruent","congruent"),
                          Position = c("left", "left","right", "right", "right", "left", "left", "left", "right", "right"),
                          Variable = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1))
```

I've attempted to use the SummarySE and subset functions, but the computation is lengthy and I'm sure there is a better solution.

```
library(Rmisc)
newdf<-data.frame(interference=c(0,0),Position =c("left","right"))
dfc <-summarySE(df, measurevar="rt",groupvars=c("Congruency","Position"))

left<-mean(subset(dfc$rt,dfc$Congruency == "congruent" & dfc$Position == "left")) - mean(subset(dfc$rt,dfc$Congruency == "incongruent"&  dfc$Position == "left"))
right<-mean(subset(dfc$rt,dfc$Congruency == "congruent"&  dfc$Position == "right")) - mean(subset(dfc$rt,dfc$Congruency == "incongruent"& dfc$Position == "right"))

newdf$interference <- c(left,right)
```

Expected Output:

```
> newdf
  interference Position
1    -186.5667     left
2      97.6500    right
```

Thanks for Reading

Comment: what is `variable` used for? `ndf <- aggregate(rt ~ ., df[, -4], mean); ave(ndf$rt, ndf$Position, FUN = diff)`

Comment: A variable like position, that could be used instead, Your solution works, but only for the specific expected output, It's not clear to me how I would modify it to calculate the mean of the subtraction by `Variable` or `Variable` and Position together. But thanks!